# Hide package in conda environment (without removing)

Tags: python, conda

I need to check if a piece of Python code works as expected when a given package is installed and when it is not. My `conda` working environment already has this package installed, and I'm looking for a way to "hide" it. I know I could:

1. Remove + test + re-install the package
2. Create a brand new environment without this package

but:

1. I need to run checks multiple times as the code evolves, and this quickly becomes a hassle
2. The environment is rather large (numerous packages) and I also need to test this on other packages, which means I'd need several similar environments

It would be ideal if I could just tell `conda`: "act as if this package is not installed". Can this be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about creating a mock module with the same name and put it first in your `PYTHONTPATH`? Its only content could be

```
raise ImportError
```

This way, any import in your code will receive an `ImportError` as if it hadn't found the module.

To revert, simply reset your `PYTHONPATH`

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion but I don't want the code to fail, I want it to check if the package is there and take a different route if it isn't.

Comment: and you are catching `ImportError` to decide the route?

Comment: I am. (more chars required...)

Comment: How about, instead of an empty mock module you have one that raises `ImportError` when imported or renaming the package folder in the `site-package` folder to mock uninstall

Comment: Raising `ImportError` manually is an easy fix that I did not think of. Would you like to add this to your answer and I'll accept it?